# How to get a Rails variable into JavaScript file (D3)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I need to grab data from by database and pass it to JavaScript file in my Rails 5 app.

In my controller I create a variable that looks like:

```
@this_anomaly = Anomaly.find_by_id(2)
```

I can obviously access it as well as in my view with something like:

```
<%= @this_anomaly.started_at %>
```

But I need to get that same data into my javascript file, which I use to draw graphs in D3 to inject into my view. How do I pass it through?

Not sure where to start, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your javascript variable in your html.erb like

```
var started_at = <%= @this_anomaly.started_at %>
```

Comment: Within a script tag? Because otherwise it will print it out as text?

Comment: *I need to get that same data into my javascript file* - it doesn't seem to me like this will do the trick.

Comment: @LaurenAH, Right, you may have to do your d3 within a script tag as well. It depends on rails turbolinks and how your js files are loaded. If the js file with d3 loads after the script on the html then the variable would be available. Try looking at a way to load external js files always after js within script tags.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put the data in your HTML in a `data` attribute

```
<div data-started-at=<%= @this_anomaly.started_at %> data-for-d3-graphics></div>
```

Then in your js file

```
let value = $('div[data-for-d3-graphics]').data('started-at');
```

I'm not sure if that is the exact syntax for `.erb` files, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

So one method that I tried that works (since I'm using d3) is to request the data in my html.erb with:

```
<div id="anomaly_data">
    <%= @this_anomaly.started_at %>
</div>
```

Then in my js file, use d3.select to store it in a variable:

```
var anomaly = d3.select("#anomaly_data").text();
```

Which works and gets me the date/times/etc without putting them through any processing! But, there must be a better way?